# Given two input arrays, return true if the words array is sorted according to the ordering array?

Tags: perl, linked-list

Want to get a better solution for this problem ?

Given two input arrays, return true if the words array is sorted according to the ordering array.
 example - words = ['cc', 'cb','bb','ac']
            ordering = ['c','b','a']
            Output: true

example - words = ['cc', 'cb','bb','ac']
            ordering = ['b','c','a']
            Output: false

I came up with the following code, in perl and its a workable solution if not super generic.

```
# example - words = ['cc', 'cb','bb','ac']
#           ordering = ['c','b','a']
#           Output: true 
my @words = ( 'cc','cb','bb','ac' );
my @ordering = ('c','b','a' );
print STDOUT "Input \@words=[",join(",",@words),"] and \@ordering=[",join(",",@ordering),"] output of \&checkWordOrdering ~[",checkWordOrdering ( \@words, \@ordering ),"]\n";

#
# example - words = ['cc', 'cb','bb','ac']
#           ordering = ['b','c','a']
#           Output: false 
@words = ( 'cc','cb','bb','ac' );
@ordering = ('b','c','a' );
print STDOUT "Input \@words=[",join(",",@words),"] and \@ordering=[",join(",",@ordering),"] output of \&checkWordOrdering ~[",checkWordOrdering ( \@words, \@ordering ),"]\n";


sub checkWordOrdering{
        my ( $wordsRef, $orderingRef ) = @_ ;
        my $orderedList = createOrderingList( $orderingRef ) ;

        foreach  my $eachWord ( @{$wordsRef}) {
                unless ( grep /$eachWord/, @{$orderedList} ) {
                        return "fasle";
                }
        }
        return "true";
}

sub createOrderingList {
    my ( $orderingRef ) = @_;
    my @OrderedList = ();
    my $lastIndex = scalar(@{$orderingRef}) - 1;

    for ( my $i=0; $i <scalar(@{$orderingRef}) ; $i++){
            my $index = $i + 1;
            if ( $i == $lastIndex ) {
                $index = -($i+1);
            }
            my $dupstr = $orderingRef->[$i].$orderingRef->[$i];
            my $str = $orderingRef->[$i].$orderingRef->[$index];
            push ( @OrderedList, ($dupstr,$str) );
    }
    #print Dumper \@OrderedList;
    return [@OrderedList];
}
```

**Output of the above code-base is :-**

```
Input @words=[cc,cb,bb,ac] and @ordering=[c,b,a] output of &checkWordOrdering ~[true]
Input @words=[cc,cb,bb,ac] and @ordering=[b,c,a] output of &checkWordOrdering ~[fasle]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem and the ordering correctly then this is a cleaner and more readable solution:

```
sub in_order {
  my ($words, $ordering) = @_;

  my $from = join '', @$ordering;
  my $to = pack 'C*', 0..$#$ordering;

  my @remapped = eval("map { tr/\Q$from\E/\Q$to\E/; \$_ } my \@t=\@\$words");

  for my $i (1..$#remapped) {
    if ($remapped[$i-1] gt $remapped[$i] ) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1
}

my @words = ( 'cc','cb','bb','ac' );
my @ordering = ('c','b','a' );

printf "words=(%s) ordering=(%s) in_order=%s\n"
    , join(',', @words), join(',', @ordering)
    , in_order(\@words,\@ordering) ? "true" : "false";

@words = ( 'cc','cb','bb','ac' );
@ordering = ('b','c','a' );

printf "words=(%s) ordering=(%s) in_order=%s\n"
    , join(',', @words), join(',', @ordering)
    , in_order(\@words,\@ordering) ? "true" : "false";
```

**output**

```
words=(cc,cb,bb,ac) ordering=(c,b,a) in_order=true
words=(cc,cb,bb,ac) ordering=(b,c,a) in_order=false
```

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/pfXquVW9) is a variant that only translates the string it has too translate. It should be faster when in_order=false, but it might be a little slower when in_order=true.

Comment: What's the `eval` for? And why have you declared `my @t` instead of using `tr///r`?

Comment: `eval` is for interpolating a variable into `tr`. See [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).  `tr///r` - I must have forgotten about that possibility being concentrated on the main idea of the algorithm.